# Proving that the sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like some help with the following problem. Thanks for any help in advance.

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be convergent sequences of positive real numbers. Let $ x_n \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} x$ and $ y_n \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} y$ and suppose that $x > 0$. Prove that the sequence $(x_nn^4 + y_nn^2)^{1/2} - x_n^{1/2}n^2$, $n \geq 1$  converges.

Comment: The universal procedure, multiply the top and missing bottom by $(x_n n^4+y_n^2)^{1/2}
+x_n^{1/2}n^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on
André Nicolas's comment,

$\begin{array}\\
(x_nn^4 + y_nn^2)^{1/2} - x_n^{1/2}n^2
&=((x_nn^4 + y_nn^2)^{1/2} - x_n^{1/2}n^2)
\dfrac{(x_nn^4 + y_nn^2)^{1/2} + x_n^{1/2}n^2}{(x_nn^4 + y_nn^2)^{1/2} + x_n^{1/2}n^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(x_nn^4 + y_nn^2)- x_nn^4}{(x_nn^4 + y_nn^2)^{1/2} + x_n^{1/2}n^2}\\
&=\dfrac{ y_nn^2}{(x_nn^4 + y_nn^2)^{1/2} + x_n^{1/2}n^2}\\
&=\dfrac{ y_n}{(x_n + y_n/n^2)^{1/2} + x_n^{1/2}}\\
\end{array}
$